# No logro mostrar el resultado de 2 consultas SQL unidas

Tags: php, html, html5, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Quiero mostrar el resultado de estas consultas, me sale el error de :

> A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in
>   C:\wamp\www\curso2.0\production\pruebaTusCursos.php on line 3

Quito ese error con:

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }
```

Pero aun no me muestra el resultado de las consultas
Este es el código :

```html
 <?php

session_start();

include("conexion.php");


$usuario2 = $_SESSION['usuario'] ;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM REGISTRO  WHERE ID_ALUMNOS = '$usuario2'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//verificar si existen registros de la busqueda
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $ID_CURSOS=$row['ID_CURSO'];
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM CURSOS  WHERE ID_CURSO= '$ID_CURSOS'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    //verificar si existen registros de la busqueda
    if($result2->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            $ID_CURSO=$row['ID_CURSO'];
            $NOMBRE_C = $row['NOMBRE_C'];
            $DURACION = $row['DURACION'];
            $CATEGORIA = $row['CATEGORIA'];
            $REQUISITOS = $row['REQUISITOS'];
            $DESCRIPCION = $row['DESCRIPCION'];
            $TIPO_CONTENIDO = $row['TIPO_CONTENIDO'];
            $INSTRUCTOR = $row['INSTRUCTOR'];
            $CORREO_INSTRUCTOR = $row['CORREO_INSTRUCTOR'];
            $REGISTRO = $row['REGISTRO'];
            $NO_LECCIONES = $row['NO_LECCIONES'];

            echo"
              <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details'>
              <form  method='POST' action='vistaGeneralAlumnos.php?msj=' >
                <div class='well profile_view'>
                    <div class='col-sm-12'>
                    <input value='".$ID_CURSO."'  type='hidden' name='id'>
                          <h4 class='brief'><i>  ".$NOMBRE_C."</i></h4>
                          <div class='left col-xs-7'>
                              <h2><strong>Incluye: </strong> ".$DURACION." / ".$NO_LECCIONES."</h2>
                              <p> <strong>Descripcion:".$DESCRIPCION." </strong></p>
                                  <ul class='list-unstyled'>
                                      <li><i class='fa fa-building'></i>Categoria:".$CATEGORIA." </li>
                                      <li><i class='fa fa-phone'></i>Contenido en:".$TIPO_CONTENIDO." </li>
                                  </ul>
                          </div>

                          <div class='right col-xs-5 text-center'>
                          <img src='images/img.jpg' alt='' class='img-circle img-responsive'>
                          </div>
                          </div>


                      <div class='col-xs-12 bottom text-center'>             
                          <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 emphasis'>
                                             
                            <a href=''> <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>
                                 <i class='fa fa-user'> </i>Vista General
                              </button></a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                </form>";                   
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "NO SE ENCONTRARON CURSOS RELACIONADOS AL ALUMNO...";
    }
}
else{
    echo "NO SE ENCONTRO EL ALUMNO...";
}

     



?>
```

Y aquí capturas de las tablas:

REGISTRO[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TABLA CURSOS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quita el espacio que tiene al inicio session_start(), dejalo así <?php sessionstart(); todo en el mismo renglón

Comment: no pasa nada bro

Comment: Veo que tiene bien los condicionales `if`, pero por que no pones un echo en los `else` y asi sabras mas facil por donde se esta yendo el hilo de ejcucion y depuraras el problema

Comment: siempre sale el error de: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\wamp\www\curso2.0\production\pruebaTusCursos.php on line 3

Comment: mira ahi modifique tu pregunta para que puedas saber como va el hilo, por otro lado, no sera que en tu archivo `include("conexion.php");`  tambien tienes una `session_start()` ?? por eso te genera ese error ?

Comment: sale que no se encontró el alumno

Comment: Y el archivo de include("conexion.php"); no tiene el session_start()

Comment: bueno, entonces si no encontro al alumno has un echo e imprime la variable `$_SESSION['usuario'] ;` para ver si esta trayendo algo

Comment: No me imprime ninguna variable de session

Comment: si tienes arriba el `session_start();` ? si lo tienes activado y no llega nada, entonces el problema no esta aqui